# Error when doing force:source:pull after creating an Email Template in a scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, lightning-email-template

I created a scratch org with the default scratch org definition file from sfdx force:project:create, and then I created an email template from the Email templates tab, and a Custom Object.

When I did force:source:pull to get the Custom Object metadata into my repo I got the following error.

> Entity of type 'EmailTemplate' named 'unfiled$public/Test_Template_1553101913374' cannot be found.

Is this some sort of bug with the cli, scratch orgs and Email Templates or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do have an open bug with the conversion between the md and dx source format underneath the hood for EmailTemplate which I believe may be causing this problem. Can you confirm what OS you are running on (Win/Mac/Lin)?

If this failure is causing other changes to not be pulled properly, you should be able to add EmailTemplate to the .forceignore file to workaround it.

Also if the failure is with the conversion, then you should be able to retrieve it with force:mdapi:retrieve if you need to get it local (in md format).

Comment: Running macOS 10.14.3 and sfdx-cli/6.56.0-e3fd846a1f (darwin-x64) node-v8.15.1. Thanks for the reply I will add it to the .forceignore file in the meantime!

Comment: Having the same issue on Mac OS, using the above mdapi command didn't pull the file down either. Really need to include some email templates with our managed package. Any way to manually pull the metadata down? Note that these are email templates created in Lightning Experience. Thanks!

Comment: Having the same issue on Win10, Cannot pull down newly created Email Templates at all.

Answer (score 1):

1- Go to your project folder.

2- Create a new folder inside your email folder and name it 'unfiled$public'.

3- Inside 'unfiled$public' folder, create two files like this

```
 1-Test_Template_1553101913374.email

 2-Test_Template_1553101913374.email-meta.xml
```

4- Save it and push it into your scratch org

5- Then try to pull. It will work

I did the same way and it worked